# Finding the number of local maxima/local minima (range) from a vector in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

the task here is to find the number of local maximas(range) or minima from a vector. I know how to find local maxima/local minima(one point from a graph) however, the local maximas are now clustered together in the vector.

To give a clearer idea, plotting out the values from the vector will produce something similar to this:

[image]

In simpler terms, I want to find the number of peaks. In this case, 6. However the peaks are not a single point, and a range of values. How am I able to find the number of peaks(range of local maxima) from the vector?

It will be greatly appreciated, if there can be some pseudocode, code examples, if not, suggestions will be appreciated too. I am using Visual Studio C++, along with QWT, QT and OpenCV for this project.

Comment: Do all the maxima have approximately the same value? Is there a minimum length of range for a maxima? For example, isn't the small peak after the first one (having a value of 0.25) considered a maxima?

Comment: I wish to avoid those small peaks to be counted in as a maxima. One idea I have is to add a condition. The condition will be such that if the value is below a certain number, it does not qualify as a maxima. How I am planning to do get the certain number is: (sum of non-zero values in vector)/(total number of non zero values in vector).

Comment: Other than that, all the maximas have approximately the same value.

Comment: Then I think it should not be that difficult. Just scan the values and whenever you get the threshold level, start the range, when you come out of the threshold level, end the range.

Comment: I so didn't see that. Obvious but didn't think about it despite wondering for 3 days plus. zzz. Please write the answer instead of comment so that I can award u the marks? Thanks(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should not be that difficult. Just scan all the values in order and whenever you get the threshold level, start the range, when you come out of the threshold level, end the particular range.

You will need to filter out the ranges that are two small.